# How to proof that Classic (Propositional) Logic and Priest's (Propositional) Logic of Paradox have the same logical truths?

Tags: logic

As far as I understand it, in Priest's "Logic of paradox" there is a proof to the effect that $\phi$ is classically valid IFF $\phi$ is valid in the Logic of Paradox (LP), that is: $\vDash_C \phi$ IFF $\vDash_{LP} \phi$.

Priest says that

> the proof from right to left is immediate since every two valued model
> is a three valued model

Why so?

Moreover, how does it work the proof from left to right?